# Get all rows which match an ID's subset of row's columns from same table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have one table:

```
+------+------+
|ID    |DESC  |
+------+------+
|1     |A     |
+------+------+
|1     |B     |
+------+------+
|2     |A     |
+------+------+
|3     |C     |
+------+------+
|4     |B     |
+------+------+
```

I want to be able to get all rows which match any of `ID` 1's `DESC`'s.  So expected output would be:

```
+------+
|ID    |
+------+
|1     |
+------+
|2     |
+------+
|4     |
+------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT %table%.ID
FROM %table% t1
JOIN %table% t2 ON t2.DESC = t1.DESC
WHERE t2.ID = 1;
```

Replace `%table%` with the name of your table

This selects the `ID` column from your table and perfoms a self join on the condition that the `DESC` column matches the `DESC` column of the first instance.

More about the self join [here](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-self-join/)